# Modify IBAN in CiviSEPA mandate

Tags: civisepa

Anybody knows whether there is a way we can modify IBAN numbers for an active mandate? Via bankswitching.be we receive a notice of a changed bank account, but CiviSEPA does not offer a way to modify the IBAN for an existing mandate. I see it is possible via the API, but if possible I would avoi needing to create a different interface.
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

CiviSepa allows certain changes to a mandate via the UI (at least if you allow changes in the SEPA-Settings - check /civicrm/admin/setting/sepa?reset=1).

When viewing a SEPA-Mandate you should have a button to change the amount of a mandate. This is (afaik) the only value that will actually change the existing mandate.

There should also be a button to update/change the mandate which will bring up a mask prefilled with the existing mandate's values that allows you to do all kind of changes.

However, technically this will end the old mandate and create a new one. I think it was designed that way because changing the IBAN or other details of a mandate (instead of creating a new one, including a new unique mandate reference) is not allowed by the SEPA-standard or at the least considered to be bad practice.

Comment: Indeed Fabian, I found the 'Replace' option to be making sense in our case. Thank you for your reply!